# Upper bound on number of lattice points of given bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lebesgue-measure, volume, integer-lattices

Consider the bounded (closed) convex region given by:

$a^Tx = b$ ,  $a^Tx = b + ||a||_2$ and $ m_1 \le x_i \le M_2 $ forall $1 \le i < n$ and $m_2 \le x_n \le M_2$ i.e two parallel hyperplanes at at unit perpedicular distance from each other within the $\mathbb{R}^n$ equivalent version of a `cuboid'.

Can we find an upper bound to the number of lattice points (points in $\mathbb{Z}^n$) contained in this region - is there some theory regarding this in the literature?

**My Idea**
My intuition suggested that the number of lattice points should be bounded by the volume. However I couldn't show this formally, moreover I am not sure what the volume of this region would be either?

Comment: You could make a crude upper bound by ignoring the first two constraints:$$\Big(\lfloor M_2 - m_2\rfloor + 1\Big) \cdot \Big(\lfloor M_2 - m_1\rfloor + 1 \Big)^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Yes, but this turns out to be too weak. Isn't there something better?